# ngrx: Router actions and syncing state

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm going through the ngrx documentation but I can't exactly follow how to sync my component state using router navigation.

Events are propagated from my child presentation components up the chain via event emission, when they reach the container they are dispatched to the store.  My container component subscribes to the store in the constructor so I am able to migrate changes down the chain from the store as well.

The problem arises when the user instantiates a component directly using either the URL or navigates via router.navigate or [routerLink]... in this case since the data from the store has not propagated to the component it's empty.

To solve this I created an Effect of type ROUTER_NAVIGATION, checked if the appropriate URL is being hit and then dispatched a RELOAD to my reducer which returns the latest copy of the state.  But there is an issue.. since the effect executes before the container is even constructed (since it isn't navigated to yet) the RELOAD dispatch never reaches it (since the subscription happens after).

What is another way to do this?

Here is what I am doing:

In my top level container component that dispatches and subscribes to the store

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   search: Observable<Search>;

   constructor(private store: Store<State>,
          private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.search = store.select('app', 'search');

    this.search.subscribe(s => {
       // do whatever
    });

   // Rest of the stuff
```

In my effect:

```
    @Effect() navigateToSearch = this.actions.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
    .filter((a: RouterNavigationAction) => a.payload.routerState.url.search('search') >= 0 )
    .map((r: RouterNavigationAction) => {
            return {type: SEARCH_RELOAD, payload: {}};
        });
```

In my reducer:

```
export function appReducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
switch (action.type) {
  case SEARCH_RELOAD: {
    return {...state };
  }
}
```

The reducer is being hit and when I introspect the state it is correct, however the component never receives the store change event.  Should I move the .subcribe to the store in my container component to perhaps afterviewinit or is there some other better way of doing this?

Edit - I tried this and it works but wondering if there is another way:

In the constructor:

```
    router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .withLatestFrom(store.select('app', 'search'))
  .subscribe(s => {
    outletBridgeService.emitStateChanged({type: BA_SEARCH_COMPLETE_IN, payload: s[1]});
  });
```

Comment: The way I do it is have independent components. No relation between them. All can dispatch events , all can get data. Also I did not understand concept of reload, store data is always available

Comment: My components are independent as well but only my container interacts with the store (i.e. subscribes to and dispatches to), the rest are presentational components that have data coming to them via @Inputs.  This is the pattern that is described in the official ngrx documentation and various other places which I am following.

The case of explicit navigation is in the ngrx4 example below but was a bit confusing to follow: https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b  (it's in the effects: handleNavigation())

Comment: Also, I am using a outlet bridge service (which acts as a shared service) for communication between the child router outlets (which handles child routes) and the container (since you can't event bind to dynamically instantiated components in the router outlet)

Comment: _"in this case since the data from the store has not propagated to the component it's empty."_ Are you saying user can go to dummy component which do not have parent presentational component ? If they have they should get data from input right ?

Comment: nope, because they are "dumb" components... the "smart" component which is the container is responsible for injecting the data into them via @Input.  However, the "smart" component gets it's state data by subscribing to store changes.  Any store changes that occur AFTER the smart component is created migrate properly, but initial state of the store should also be populated.  This does not happen because until a store change occurs there are no events, which is why in the above example I hooked into the "NavigationEnd" router event and then fired a RELOAD to the reducer to force a store change.